# Vue - Preload dynamic components

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-dynamic-components

In vue, one can render dynamic components by this: 
`<keep-alive>  <component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component> </keep-alive>` 
If components are A,B,C and currentTabComponent = A, component A will be rendered first and will be kept alive. Then upon clicking other components, B and C will render eventually and all components will be kept alive. 
 My question is how to render them such a way, where they all will be alive just after rendering instead of only the first one. I've tried mount and before mount lifecycle hooks but they doesn't work. 
To summarise, If I assume keep alive is an array under the hood, default behaviour is: keepalive[A] , then keepalive[A,B] at last keepalive [A,B,C] 
I want it to be like this at the start: keepalive[A,B,C].

Comment: seems like you want to load all components on mount, but only display one at a time - you probably don't need `<keep-alive>` in that case - seems like what you really want is `v-show`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've trird with v-show before, it doesn’t work